# Build Errors on Custom Controls Converting Web Site to Web Application in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vs-web-application-project

I'm converting a VS 2010 Web Site to a VS 2015 Web Application in C#.  I have a Custom Control Project that is being accessed correctly now.  However, I am getting 4000+ build errors on perhaps every one of them.  Yet, all I do is open the .aspx page and build, and the errors go away.

I don't know if this was because the reference wasn't working when I ran the Convert to Web Application or not.

Is there anyway to refresh all of this without having to open every page?